# Model with huge number of fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have model Car and fields vin:uniq  a_field1 a_field2 a_field3 .. a_field20 b_field1 b_field2 b_field3 .. b_field30. I have two kinds of users Mechanik and Manager. Mechanik can see and edit a_  parameters and manager is able to see and edit b_ parameters. Nobody can edit vin.  Both of users can create Car with vin and a_ parameters for Mechanik and vin and b_ parameters for manager.  Is it better to divide the model car and connect them by has_one and belongs_to or have one big model with all parameters. Maybe there is another better approach? How it should looks like?

Comment: I would not have a model with lots of fields. It's possible you have to back up and rethink what you're trying to model. Kind of step outside the box you're in. You might be able to separate the fields by concern. Let's say that some of them have to do with the transmission and others the interior. There are two objects that would be associated with the car. I realize that's not accurate to your example, but it's meant to illustrate separation by concerns. Your separation by 'role' is not a bad idea, but I don't have enough context to evaluate it detail-wise.

Comment: I don't know what to say more. Do you have any questions? I'd like to do it well, but I don't know what is the best approach.

Comment: You don't really need to say more. I was just saying that given what you've said about separating by role, it seems reasonable to me. There could be systemic, business or other reasons that would affect the decision process but I'm not (nor should I be) privy to those things.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you talking to have two models connected by has one and belongs to ?

Comment: To implement a role based separation of concerns, I would keep the Car model. I would find a way to pull the attributes out to other models. One way is that the VIN stays on the car, and you have  ManagerAttributes and MechanikAttributes models. These are both connected to the car by has_one -> belongs_to associations with the has_one on the Car. but my original point is that this is only one way to approach

Comment: Thanks a lot for your commens